# How can I get the email template ID by code? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

How can I get the template ID by its template name?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this below code to get your email template ID by code :

```
protected $emailTemplate;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Email\Model\BackendTemplate $emailTemplate
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->emailTemplate = $emailTemplate;
    ...
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    $email_template = $this->emailTemplate->load('New Pickup Order', 'template_code');
    echo $email_template->getId();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rohan!

Comment: Happy coding :) happy to help!!

Comment: Nice solution Rohan, only one comment, ... the last line should be getId() rather than getTemplateId()... Thanks again.